# Why does SCNNode move all over the place using ARKit?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I have 2 SCNNode's in my view and when I shake my phone's camera, the node's go crazy and start moving to weird places by themselves. Does anyone know how to fix that and make them stay in one place?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The camera is likely losing its real world position reference when you shake the device.

Comment: So is there a way to prevent that from happening? I only have this set for my node's : item.scale = SCNVector3(x: 0.087, y: 0.087, z: 0.087)
        item.position = SCNVector3(0.99, 0.755, 0.3)

Comment: @Hal Sorry to bother you…… I'm struggling with a SceneKit problem could you help me out? Question:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52428397/confused-about-orthographic-projection-of-camera-in-scenekit